# ImageField with thumbnail and generated upload_to path

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-settings

I have following code in my models.py:

```
def product_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'img/products/%s/large/%s' % (instance.uuid, filename,)

def thumb_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'img/products/%s/thumb/%s' % (instance.uuid, filename,)


class Product(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Cena")

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_upload_to,null=True,blank=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to=thumb_upload_to,null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, force_update=False, force_insert=False, thumb_size=(120,120)):
        image = Image.open(self.image)
        image.thumbnail(thumb_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        temp_handle = StringIO()
        image.save(temp_handle, 'png')
        temp_handle.seek(0) # rewind the file
        suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.image.name)[-1],
                                 temp_handle.read(),
                                 content_type='image/png')
        self.thumb.save(suf.name+'.png', suf, save=False)
        super(Product, self).save(force_update, force_insert)
```

I ran into issues, which I'm not able to fix:
- image path is generated properly for original image (image field) but not for the thumbnail (thumb field).

It looks like:

- img/products/6fddb163-435b-11e3-98fe-843835614698/large/IMG_0171.JPG **(good for image)**
- img/products/None/thumb/IMG_0171.JPG.png **(bad for thumb)**

Also, I am not sure if paths in admin panel are generated properly, because they are absolute (example: `http://localhost:8000/admin/app/product/1/img/products/6fddb163-435b-11e3-98fe-843835614698/large/IMG_0171.JPG`) - and I can't reach them. img directory is being created directly in django project directory, I don't know how to change this to be created within static directory.

Could you help me to solve issue with thumb path and admin path?

Comment: I've addressed one of the issues:
I had to set proper MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT paths.

Comment: You can add your own answer to your own question and accept it